# What is the purpose of rails:update:bin rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not able to find much information about this task. I can't understand its purpose or when it should be run. Could someone explain what this task is about and why/when it's useful?

Answer (score 5):

In case of **Rails 5.0** onward this rake command is renamed as **app:update:bin** and can be run as

```
rake app:update:bin
```

or the rails way

```
rails app:update:bin
```

It will show you output like below:

```
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  bin/update
  create  bin/yarn
```

and this will be used to create executable binaries. ie if you run `rails console` etc. It required bin directory to have that script. Without this It will show the error like below:

```
 bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/deploy/apps/sahaya/shared/config/boot (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `rake rails:update:bin` task creates [binstubs](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs) for `bundle`, `rails` and `rake`.

> Binstubs are wrapper scripts around executables (sometimes referred to as "binaries", although they don't have to be compiled) whose purpose is to prepare the environment before dispatching the call to the original executable.

In other words, the binstubs makes sure that the correct version of the gem included in your project is executed, achieving a similar result to `bundle exec your_command`, but without having to explicitly type it every time.

It is used to re-create your binstubs when they got removed for some reason, or when you are upgrading from Rails 3 that didn't provide them by default.